# <link rel="canonical" href="/relative/url" />

Tags: 8, google-search-console

Drupal 8 creates `<link rel="canonical" href="/relative/url" />` by default.  support.google.com says:

> Use absolute paths rather than relative paths with the rel="canonical"
>   link element.
>
> Use this structure: 
>   https://www.example.com/dresses/green/greendresss.html Not this
>   structure: /dresses/green/greendress.html

I used the Google Search Console URL Inspection and found Google does not recognize relative urls as canonical.  It says:

> User-declared canonical N/A

I believe this is causing some indexing problems for our multiple language website.  How can we convert the canonical urls to absolute as recommended by Google?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following function updates the rel tags in the head section of all pages on a website.  The "revision" and "shortlink" tags are deleted using unset(). The "canonical" tag is converted from a relative to an absolute url.  This function should be called from modulename_preprocess_html() of your custom module.

```
function canonical_shortlink_revision(&$variables) {

  foreach($variables['page']['content']['system_main']['#attached']['html_head_link'] as $key => $value) {

    if( ($value[0]["rel"] === "revision") || ($value[0]["rel"] === "shortlink") )
      unset($variables['page']['content']['system_main']['#attached']['html_head_link'][$key]);

    if($value[0]["rel"] === "canonical") {
      $href = $variables['page']['content']['system_main']['#attached']['html_head_link'][$key][0]["href"];
      $href = \Drupal::request()->getSchemeAndHttpHost() . $href;
      $variables['page']['content']['system_main']['#attached']['html_head_link'][$key][0]["href"] = $href;
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: This is being addressed in Drupal core as well.  https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3003713

Answer (score 3):

The [metatag](https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag) module gives you the ability to overwrite the 'canonical' metatag:

- On the module's settings page (`/admin/config/search/metatag`)
- Edit the `General` type
- Under `Advanced` you'll find the **Canonical** field
- Set the field's value to `[current-page:url:absolute]`
- Save

That should do it. The instructions above are for Drupal 8.

**Update 1:**

If you are comfortable using hooks and working with PHP you may also use a theme hook (`hook_page_attachments_alter`) to achieve the same thing. [Here's](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_page_attachments_alter/8.6.x) the api spec on drupal.org for the function.